# wpf WebBrowser element enter and leave events stop working

Tags: wpf, browser

I need to highlight some span elements in my html and show a popup. The following code does the highlighting, but the enter and leave events stop working after a short time in use (maybe 20 enters and leaves). If I add the popup the events will stop working sooner - usually after just one or two calls. I have no idea how to debug this as there is no exception, the events just stop getting called.

I wrote this code from documentation as I couldn't find anyone using the element event handlers like this: HTMLElementEvents2_onmouseenterEventHandler

Note this code requires "using mshtml;" and a reference to the COM 'Microsoft HTML object library'

```
 void mBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("LoadCompleted");
        var doc = (IHTMLDocument2)mBrowser.Document;            
        foreach (IHTMLElement elem in doc.all)
        {
            if (elem.tagName == "SPAN")
            {
                mshtml.HTMLElementEvents2_Event iEvt;
                iEvt = (HTMLElementEvents2_Event)elem;
                iEvt.onmouseenter += new HTMLElementEvents2_onmouseenterEventHandler(onMouseEnter);
                iEvt.onmouseleave += new HTMLElementEvents2_onmouseleaveEventHandler(onMouseLeave);
                //iEvt.onmouseover  += new HTMLElementEvents2_onmouseoverEventHandler(onMouseOver);
                Debug.WriteLine("span: " + elem.innerHTML);
            }
        }
    }

    void onMouseEnter(mshtml.IHTMLEventObj e)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine(" mouse enter! " + e.srcElement.innerHTML);
        //mPopup.IsOpen = true;
        //mPopup.HorizontalOffset = e.x;
        //mPopup.VerticalOffset = e.y;
        e.srcElement.style.backgroundColor = "#CCCCCC";

    }
    void onMouseLeave(mshtml.IHTMLEventObj e)
    {
        //mPopup.IsOpen = false;
        Debug.WriteLine(" mouse leave! " + e.srcElement.innerHTML);
        e.srcElement.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
    }
```

Comment: Something getting garbage collected? I assume in the code above I'm modifying the elements in the webbrowser document property so nothing should be going away..

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the elements events on static field to avoid garbage collection.

```
static mshtml.HTMLElementEvents2_Event iEvt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a list of the element events around to avoid garbage collection.

```
List<mshtml.HTMLElementEvents2_Event> mEvts = new List<HTMLElementEvents2_Event>();
```

and

```
mEvts.Add(iEvt);
```